# How to register a Shortcut Key for application shortcut link during setup?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, setup-project, setup-deployment, windows-shell

How can I register a shortcut key, for example <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, as shortcut key for my application during the setup?

When you install an application:

1. You can create desktop shortcut link.
2. You can Right Click on the shortcut and choose to show Properties.
3. In properties windows in, `Shortcut` Tab you see `Shortcut key : none`.
4. If you click on text box, you can register a shortcut manually for your application by pressing desired shortcut key combinations.

My requirement is registering the shortcut key for application during setup, so the end user doesn't need to do it manually on each client that install the application.  Then when the user use that shortcut combination, the application opens.

I'm using visual studio 2010 setup and deployment project.

[image: Shortcut key for application]

Comment: Not enough information to provide a complete answer to the question. How is the setup program creating the shortcut? Do you have access to this code? If so, it is simple. Call [IShellLink::SetHotkey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761045(v=vs.85).aspx). More general information on creating shortcuts is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969393.aspx#Shellink_Creating_Shortcut), should you need to write the code to create the shortcut yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a shortcut link programmatically and assign a shortcut key to it.
Based on the way you create the setup, you can decide how and when you run such code.

Based on comments since you are using visual studio setup and deployment project to create setup, you can create a [`CustomAction`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/d9k65z2d(v=vs.100).aspx) and Override its  `OnAfterInstall` method and create shortcut using below code.

Don't forget to add a reference to `Windows Script Host Object Model` using add reference window under com type libraries.

Also when you add the custom action to your setup project, set [`CustomActionData`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2w2fhwzz(v=vs.100).aspx) property to `/path="[TARGETDIR]\"`, this way you will be able to get the path that user selected to install application using `Context.Parameters["path"]`.

**Here is the code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Configuration.Install;

namespace CustomActions
{
    [RunInstaller(true)]
    public partial class Installer1 : Installer
    {
        public Installer1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        protected override void OnAfterInstall(System.Collections.IDictionary savedState)
        {
            base.OnAfterInstall(savedState);

            IWshRuntimeLibrary.WshShell WshShell = new IWshRuntimeLibrary.WshShell();
            object strDesktop = (object)"Desktop";
            string shortcutAddress = (string)WshShell.SpecialFolders.Item(ref strDesktop)
                                     + @"\Shortcut to YourApplication.lnk";
            IWshRuntimeLibrary.IWshShortcut oShellLink =  (IWshRuntimeLibrary.IWshShortcut)WshShell.CreateShortcut(shortcutAddress);
            oShellLink.TargetPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Context.Parameters["path"], "YourApplication.exe");
            oShellLink.Hotkey = "Ctrl+Alt+V";
            oShellLink.Description = "Shortcut To YourApplication";
            oShellLink.Save();
        }

    }
}
```

**Download Example**

You can download a working example from the following repository:

- [r-aghaei/ShortcutKeyForApplication](https://github.com/r-aghaei/ShortcutKeyForApplication)
- [Zip File](https://github.com/r-aghaei/ShortcutKeyForApplication/archive/master.zip)

Comment: When user install application that time he select the installation path.
i want this path,so how it is possible?

Comment: It depends on the technology that you use for creating setup. For example when you create set up using visual studio setup and deployment project template, you can create a [`CustomAction`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/d9k65z2d(v=vs.100).aspx) and override its methods and perform the task there.

Comment: What's the technology that you use for installation?

Comment: visual studio 2010 version and c#

Comment: Hi Reza, finally i complete task using custom action and add installer class in installer class include install method  instead added  my custom code and set to fix client installation path and this path is assign is our target path. .......thanks lot reza .......